# POST to server results in GET request

Tags: objective-c, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, http-method

I'm trying to do a simple POST request to a server, with this code:

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@", self.email.text, ..]; // .. simplified keychainItem 
NSData *postEncoded = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO]; 
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postEncoded length]]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eng.studev.groept.be/web2.0/a11_web02/testApp.php"]; 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setURL:url]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setHTTPBody:postEncoded]; 

self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When debugging on the server, this actually results in a GET request. That explains why I'm getting a PHP error when trying to read $_POST[ ] variables. Bottom line: why isn't the setHTTPMethod: being accepted?

(extra information: when just coding in PHP on the server, use of POST works normally)